# Is there any way to automatically find the local IP address for use with TcpListener?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, server, ip-address, winsock

Using VC++ 2010, .NET 4

Is there any way to automatically find the local IP address for use with TcpListener?  I can now put one in manually:

```
Int32 port = 36457;
IPAddress^ localAddr = IPAddress::Parse("192.168.1.254");
TcpListener^ server = gcnew TcpListener(localAddr, port);
```

But opening on a different machine will then fail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to find the local IP address for a machine as it can be part of multiple networks and can have multiple IP-addresses per network. (My computer has about 10 networks and I have server with 4 IP-addresses on a single network)

The only portable addresses to bind are 0.0.0.0 and the 127.0.0.1 network. Binding to 127.0.0.1 (also known under the alias localhost makes it only reachable from the machine itself and not from the network. Binding to 0.0.0.0 makes it reachable on every address on every network. Firewall rules must be set accordingly. Instead of 0.0.0.0 you can also use IPAddress.Any .

Most application let the user set this via configuration file, command line parameter or asking the user directly.

Answer (score 0):

As long als you want to listen on all networks you are connected to, you can use "localhost" instead of the ip adress.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use IPAddress.Any, or IPAddress.IPv6Any? This way, your network situation will be detected automatically. In generally, I wouldn't use a specific IP Address unless you know in advance which server with a static IP is being used, and even then I'd limit myself to one specified in a config file of some sort.